# Exactly when were JavaScript promises created?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have been using promises for a while in my React code. But I have to include the babel polyfill library to support promises and map function for browsers which do not support latest JavaScript ES6, let's call these old browsers.

Now what confuses me is how are async functions written in old browsers. Async is not supported in Internet Explorer, so how are they written?
I have also read that promises are not async themsselves but a tool to manage async functions. Then what are the core async functions that a developer can write if he wants to develop his own promise functionality?
Is the `setTimeout` function only way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

### The old method for async: Callbacks

The usual way to handle asynchronous functions without promises is with *callback functions*. An example of that is the `setTimeout` function that you mentioned (see documentation on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)), which takes a (callback) function as its first argument, that will be called when the timer is done.

There are many other functions that are designed this way, perhaps most notably, the AJAX API: [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). This allows you register event listeners (a.k.a. callback functions), which are called when the AJAX call is done:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
oReq.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
oReq.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
oReq.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled);

oReq.open();
```

Speaking of event listeners, the standard DOM event listeners are also examples of async handled with callbacks. Here is an example for the click event (again from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click)):

```html
<div id="test"></div>

<script>
  document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
    // display the current click count inside the clicked div
    event.target.textContent = "click count: " + event.detail;
  }, false);
</script>
```

### The new method: Promises

So, where do promises come into this story? Promises is a fairly simple abstraction which is (at least in JS), built on top of callbacks. In other words, (almost) all promise API functions in JS call functions like those mentioned above, behind the scenes.

A [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is constructed by giving an executor, which will get two callback functions, one for signaling success (and returning a value), `resolve` and one for failure, `reject`:

```
var p = new Promise( /* executor */ function(resolve, reject) { ... } )
```

For example, we can construct a timer promise like this:

```
new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {setTimeout(resolve, delay);};
```

or an AJAX promise like this:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    oReq.addEventListener("load", resolve);
    oReq.addEventListener("error", reject);
    oReq.addEventListener("abort", reject);

    oReq.open();
});
```